# How to load the whole dataset to GPU

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, computer-vision

I have dataset of 1550 images 3x112x112. When i am training my model I create dataset wia ImageFolder and then use DataLoader. It takes so much time because of reading from memory every time. I have enough gpu memory to load the whole dataset at once. It will be much faster. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the images as an attribute of the dataset, put it on the GPU at initialization, and let `__getitem__` return images from this directly.

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class GPUDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.len = 1550
        self.data = torch.randn(self.len, 3, 112, 112).cuda()  # ~ 223 MB

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len
    
dataset = GPUDataset()
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=4)

batch = next(iter(loader))
print(batch.device, batch.shape)    # cuda:0 torch.Size([4, 3, 112, 112])
```

This is meant to be a quick fix for small datasets. For larger datasets, consider more advanced solutions such as [lmdb](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/).